# What's it called when a male seahorse gets "inseminated"?

Tags: terminology, reproduction, marine-biology

I am looking for the scientific term for the process where a male seahorse receives eggs from the female. For example, we usually say, "the male inseminates the female with sperm." What is the correct term to use for seahorses? Would you say "the female inseminates the male with eggs", or is another term more appropriate?

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**
I think that "*egg deposition*" by means of the female "ovipositor" seems the most commonly used terminology.

**Background**
A cursory Google search yielded quite a few alternatives, ordered here from the most fancy to the least:

- ...*that are **deposited** directly into the brood pouch* ... [(Look *et al*., 2007)](https://jeb.biologists.org/content/210/3/432)
- ...***transferring*** their eggs directly into the male brood pouch... [(Masonjones & Lewis, 1997)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1447527?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
- ...[*the female **injects** her eggs into the male’s pouch using her penis-like ovipositor*](https://www.earth.com/news/male-seahorses-give-birth/)
- ...*[once all the eggs are **inserted**](https://www.thoughtco.com/seahorse-facts-2291858)*

<sub>**References**

**-** [Look *et al*., *J Exp Biol* (2007); **210**: 432-7](https://jeb.biologists.org/content/210/3/432)

**-** [Masonjones & Lewis, *Copeia* 1996; (3): 634-40](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1447527?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)</sub>